# MSP430FR5969 not going to sleep

Tags: c, embedded, msp430

I am using MSP430FR5969 and trying to put it into LMP4 mode. I cannot enter the LPM4 mode with global interrupts enabled. The code I am using is as below. Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

The entire code can be seen in this [link](https://pastebin.com/YRN41vQi)

```c
int main(void) {

    Init_Clock();
    Init_GPIO();
    Init_UART();

    printf("test \n");
    __delay_cycles(1000);

    EUSCI_A_UART_disable(EUSCI_A0_BASE);


    reset_gpio();

    PMMCTL0_H = PMMPW_H;                // Open PMM Registers for write
    PMMCTL0_L &= ~(SVSHE);              // Disable high-side SVS
    PMMCTL0_L |= PMMREGOFF;             // and set PMMREGOFF
    PMMCTL0_H = 0;                      // Lock PMM Registers


    __bic_SR_register(GIE);
    __bis_SR_register(LPM4_bits);
    __no_operation();
}
```

Comment: @botje Never edit questions to completely remove a language tag. These tags are not only used for what the topic is about but also to pick the default code formatting. Meaning that a programming language tag on a post containing code is always appropriate and pretty much mandatory.

Comment: Where is the "for-ever" loop? This program will very quickly jump out from main() and into "la-la-land" and likely crash from there.

Comment: @lundin I am testing the current consumption in LPM4.5. The micro will forever stay in low-power mode.

Comment: Except it apparently does not, so you need to trouble-shoot it, yeah? Where do you end up if you single step through this with the debugger? Does it hang?

Comment: It does not hang. It goes to sleep with a consumption of 70uA while the correct consumption in LPM4.5 is 0.2uA.

Comment: The title says "MSP430FR5969 not going to sleep"... I don't understand what you are asking about then.

Comment: Check whether the example program `msp430fr59xx_lpm4-5_02.c` works. What is connected to the GPIOs that you have configures as inputs?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not reading your code.  but i will remind you that certain peripherals and clock contrasts can interfere with low power modes, even a pending interrupt.  review the low power modes section of the specific data sheet and family guide.  yeah, you'll get to know your target soc much better.  the 5969 can really kick butt but it is one the most complex msp430's.

Comment: Welcome! It would be helpful to provide some more context on how peripherals and clock configs might interfere with sleep. Even if you aren't able to read the full code, specific references to the datasheet based on the registers set in the OP's small code sample would still be very helpful to the OP and other readers.